# Access VBA DAO | ADO Bloating Database on MakeTable Query

Tags: ms-access, vba, dao

I have a process that updates an Access Database from Oracle data three times a day to get latest information. Current production process involves:

- Create New Access Table (t1) of Most Current Data
- Move Previous Version of Data to backup version (t to t2)
- Move Current Data to Main table (t1 to t)

The reason it's done this way is in case the current data fails, users can still access earlier version of data until we can troubleshoot current data or until the next run.

There are many of the processes that we inherited and I am refactoring the process so we can trap and alert errors and stop downstream processes from running when earlier processes fail.

I've developed the following function using DAO so that I can take advantage of `Execute` to trap errors and bow out of the whole process gracefully. However, this process bloats the database greatly and in all my searching I cannot find a way around this. Most of the research I have done points to clearing out `DAO.Recordsets` and `DAO.QueryDefs`, neither of which I deal with in the DDL statements. I created a similar function with ADO as well, but the same issue persists.

Is there any way to clear the temp memory created in Access from this statements after executing so the code can continue without have the DB grow beyond 2GB size limit? Or perhaps it's just better to run the queries with `DoCmd.RunSQL` and build error trapping with `GoTo`. I'd like to avoid this but will settle on this if it's the only way.

Function below:

```
Function ExecuteSQL(db As DAO.Database, sQuery As String) As Boolean

'*******************************************************************
'**    Sub:     ExecuteSQL
'**    Purpose: Stores current copy of Daily Eff Date table from Daily Eff Table1 and backs up previous version in Daily Eff Date2
'**    Notes:   Requires reference to Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library (or equivalent)
'*******************************************************************

Dim wSpace As DAO.Workspace
Set wSpace = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)

On Error GoTo ErrHandler

With wSpace

    .BeginTrans

    db.Execute sQuery, dbFailOnError

    .CommitTrans

    ExecuteSQL = True

End With

LeaveExecuteSQL:

    wSpace.Close
    Exit Function

ErrHandler:

    wSpace.Rollback
    Resume LeaveExecuteSQL

End Function
```

Here is an example of how Function is called.

```
If Not ExecuteSQL(CurrentDb, "Daily Sub ALL") Then 'Bring Submission Data into Access

    strSubject = "ERROR in Creating The Daily Effective Date Table"
    GoTo LeaveRunProcess

End If
```

Here is SQL for `Daily Sub ALL`:

```
SELECT PRODCT_EFF_DT, Left([DWCFEUL5_DEV_SUB_RPT_STATUS_SUBM_ALL_NM]![PRODUCT_SIC_CD],4) AS Expr1, Left([PRODUCT_SIC_CD],4) AS [SIC Short], INS_RQMT_PRODCT_NO, CMPNY_REGN_NM, PROCESSING_REGION, PROCESSING_RGN_NM, CMPNY_CD, CMPNY_NM, PUC_NAME, UW_REGION_NAME, PUC_NO, CLIENT_NAME, CLIENT_NUMBER, ACCOUNT_NUMBER, DUNS_NUMBER, DUNS_PARENT, PRODUCER_NUMBER, PRODUCER_NAME, PRODUCER_CONTACT, PRODCR_CNTCT_PRSN_NO, PRODUCT_TYPE, BRANCH_TYPE, BRANCH_NAME, DEPT_NO, NEW_DEPT_NO, DEPT_CD, DEPT_NM, NEW_DEPT_NM, NEW_PRFT_CENTR_NO, PROFT_CNTR_NM, NEW_PRFT_CENTR_NM, EXP_POLICY_NO, EXPPOLICYNO10, POLICY_NO, POLICYNO10, PRODCT_ATCHMT_PNT_AMT, DED_AMT, LMT_AMT, PRODCT_EXP_DT, QUOTE_BY_DT, PRODCT_DESIRBLTY, NEW_PRODCR_NM, PRODCT_SUCCESS_CHNC, WIN_CARR_NAME, INCUMBENT_INS_CARR, PRODCT_EFF_MONTH, LINE_OF_BUSINESS, PRODCT_NO, PROFIT_CENTER, EXP_PREMIUM, UNDERWRITER_NAME, EMPL_ID, STATE, LAST_UPDT_TS, PREM_AMT, DT_RECEIVED, DT_RESERVED, DT_ASSIGNED, DT_WORKING, DT_QUOTED, DT_BOUND, DT_ISSUED, DT_BOOKED, DT_MAILED, DT_DECLINED, DT_QUOTE_NOT_WRITTEN, CURR_STATUS, CURR_STATUS_CD, CURR_STATUS_CHG_USR, CURR_STATUS_EFF_DT, UW_ASISTANT_NAME, COMPANY_TYPE, CREATE_DT, CREATE_USR, PRM_FINCG_IND, BNKRPCY_STAT_CD, BRKR_MNSCRPT_FORMS_IND, UNDLYG_CNF_WRITN_IND, PRODUCT_SIC_CD, ACCT_SIC, ACCT_SIC_DESC, ACCT_SIC_PCT, PROG_TYP_CD, EXT_REPT_IND, MOT_TRK_LIAB_FIL, MOT_TRK_CRG_FIL, SUBJ_TO_AUDIT, COMP_RATED_IND, CONSENT_TO_RATE, IND_RISK_RATING, NY_FREE_TRD_ZONE, EPOL_DELIVERED, PAYDEX_SCORE, CREDIT_SCORE, FINANCIAL_STRESS_SCORE, YEARS_IN_BUSINESS, DNB_NO, DNB_NAME, DNB_PARENT_NO, DNB_HEADQUARTERS_NO, DNB_ADDRESS_LINE1, DNB_ADDRESS_LINE2, DNB_ZIPCODE, DNB_CITY, DNB_STATE, DNB_COUNTRY_CODE, COMMERCIAL_CREDIT_SCORE, START_YEAR, CURRENT_CONTROL_YEAR, NAICS_CODE, INSRD_NM, PRODCR_LONG_NAME, SIR_AMOUNT, EMAIL_ADDRS_TXT, SUB_PRODUCER_NO, SUB_PRODUCER_CODE, SUB_PRODUCER_NM, SUB_PRODUCER_ADDRESS_LINE1, SUB_PRODUCER_ADDRESS_LINE2, SUB_PRODUCER_ADDRESS_LINE3, SUB_PRODUCER_CITY, SUB_PRODUCER_STATE, SUB_PRODUCER_ZIPCODE, PRODUCER_PHONE_NO, SHOPPING, ASSOC_NO, VIABILITY_SCORE, POLICY_ISSUED_BY, ASSOCIATE_UW, FEIN_N0, PRODUCER_FEIN 
INTO [Daily Eff Date1]
FROM DWCFEUL5_DEV_SUB_RPT_STATUS_SUBM_ALL_NM
WHERE (((PRODCT_EFF_DT)>#1/1/2015#) AND ((NEW_PRFT_CENTR_NM) Not Like "Hawaii"));
```

Comment: Does the bloating happen in each step?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Bloating happens mainly when I run the MakeTable queries. Dropping tables and renaming them works well. The issue is that there are few iterations and on the 2nd one, the database grows beyond 2GB and becomes inoperable.

Comment: Have you tried to do it as a pass through query?

Comment: Nps, I had a similar issue the other day, and tracked it down to a tiny "nuance" in the connection string, ended up seeming a little faster, and no bloating, took loads of searching to :)

Comment: @Nathan_Sav ... issue with passthrough option is that I loss `dbFailOnError` option, which I want to keep.

Comment: You could look at creating a class to trap the error, so withevents on an ADODB.Connection, then execute the SQL, trapping error on Connection Event, put the code I've used in the answer

Comment: @Nathan_Sav - Thanks. Will look into it.

Comment: Would it make any difference to create the temp table in an outside linked database table? Also if you're trapping for FailOnerror, do you need the Transaction wrapping? That must add some extra database memory consumption.

Comment: I would also try `.AccDb` if it is an `.mdb` file, and maybe Compact and Repair as a final option. Access usually reserves more space than it needs for performance reasons.

Comment: @dbmitch - thanks for the idea. Maybe the transaction is a bit superfluous, but it's not affecting the bloat, at least as far as I can tell when I step through line-by-line.

Comment: You can't step thru the SQL line by line - it's a bulk update - doesn't the bloat happen on `db.Execute sQuery, dbFailOnError` - that's where the transactions will have to be recorded

Comment: @dbmitch - yes. that's exactly where it happens. I guess I misunderstood your question about transaction wrapping. I was just saying the `Begin` and `Commit` cause no bloating.

Comment: Gotcha - one other thing I might try depending on its feasibility. Can you remove all the indexes from your temp table? Then call a routine to add them afterwards - that will surely reduce the time for completion and be less for the operation to track changes

Answer (score 2):

NOT AN ANSWER SUPPORT FOR COMMENT

```
Option Compare Database

Private WithEvents conCUSTOM_CONNECTION As ADODB.CONNECTION

Public Event evtEXECUTEERROR(ByVal pError As ADODB.Error)
Public Event evtEXECUTESUCCESS()

Public Sub INITIALISE_CONNECTION(con As ADODB.CONNECTION)
    Set conCUSTOM_CONNECTION = con
End Sub

Private Sub conCUSTOM_CONNECTION_ExecuteComplete(ByVal RecordsAffected As Long, _
                    ByVal pError As ADODB.Error, adStatus As ADODB.EventStatusEnum, _
                    ByVal pCommand As ADODB.Command, ByVal pRecordset As ADODB.Recordset, _
                    ByVal pConnection As ADODB.CONNECTION)
    If pError Is Nothing Then
        RaiseEvent evtEXECUTESUCCESS
    Else
        RaiseEvent evtEXECUTEERROR(pError)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same issue where my database is bloating on raw data import. VBA is not allowed to call Compact & Repair on a non-split database. Instead of splitting the database and compacting the backend routinely, I decided to use the database object (DAO) to create a temp database, import the data, query from that temp database back to original and then delete the temp database. Base code shown below:

```
Sub tempAccessDatabaseImport()
    Dim mySQL As String
    Dim tempDBPath As String
    Dim myWrk As DAO.Workspace
    Dim tempDB As DAO.Database
    Dim myObject

    'Define temp access database path
    tempPathArr = Split(Application.CurrentProject.Path, "\")
    For i = LBound(tempPathArr) To UBound(tempPathArr)
        tempDBPath = tempDBPath + tempPathArr(i) + "\"
    Next i
    tempDBPath = tempDBPath + "tempDB.accdb"

    'Delete temp access database if exists
    Set myObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If myObject.FileExists(tempDBPath) Then
        myObject.deleteFile (tempDBPath)
    End If

    'Open default workspace
    Set myWrk = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)

    'DAO Create database
    Set tempDB = myWrk.CreateDatabase(tempDBPath, dbLangGeneral)

    'DAO - Import temp xlsx into temp Access table
    mySQL = "SELECT * INTO tempTable FROM (SELECT vXLSX.*FROM [Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=" & RAWDATAPATH & "].[" & WORKSHEETNAME & "$] As vXLSX)"

    'DAO Execute SQL
    Debug.Print mySQL
    Debug.Print
    tempDB.Execute mySQL, dbSeeChanges

    'Do Something Else

    'Close DAO Database object
    tempDB.Close
    Set tempDB = Nothing

    myWrk.Close
    Set myWrk = Nothing

    'Delete temp access database if exists
    If myObject.FileExists(tempDBPath) Then
        'myObject.deleteFile (tempDBPath)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This should probably only be a comment, but I don't have the privileges for that.

"Compact & Repair"ing a database will help with size issues. You can use the Access visual interface to do that on a regular basis or programatically:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb220986(v=office.12).aspx

Compressing the file (only works on NTFS) will reduce the physical hard drive space occupied (as with ZIP or RAR) while improving speed with hard-drive access (fewer spins in the case of hard disks, and less bytes to read). You can even apply NTFS compression to a file on a network share.

Just today I further reduced the size of an Access database by simply copying all of the objects (it only consists of tables) to a new database file. So it became several times smaller even though I had already compacted it.

I said it's only a comment since it only helps, not solve every side of the problem in every way.

If you can, using append queries instead of make table ones might be worth trying too.